# Hit my new 2019 Mazda 3 front rim on curb , not sure if it’s OK or safe or needs repair?

Tags: tires

Hit my new 2019 Mazda 3 front rim on curb , not sure if it’s OK or safe or needs repair?

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a scrape to me, only cosmetic damage, and not any impairment of the wheel's structure or strength. Were it my car (and it has been, in the past), I'd be comfortable continuing to use the wheel, 'tho might get some silver paint to touch up the scrapes.

If you're concerned, you could drive the car to a tire or wheel shop, and get their opinion.

Comment: There's a place called [KwickSilver](http://kwicksilverusa.com/) that does this sort of wheel repair. My experience with them has been excellent.

Answer (score -2):

There are usually two things happen when you hit a curb this way. These are:
1. Cosmetic damage, and
2. Wheel alignment isn't current anymore
If the tire doesn't lose its pressure it is safe to drive.

I drive a lot and if I badly hit a curb fuel consumption goes up and the tire is wearing out quicker. I would recommend to get wheels alignment done (and maybe wheel balancing) and from functional perspective it will be as new.

Comment: Downvoated. "If the tire doesn't lose it's pressure it is safe to drive" is most assuredly incorrect. Tire sidewalls can be damaged such that they fail not right away, but some time later.

Comment: Wasn't Sid asking about the rim damage? My answer was based on the photo provided. AFAIK tire sidewall damages could be visually observed (which isn't present on the photo) due to internal cord rupture and I don't it is safe to drive with these ones. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, I see your point, @Alex, as to the original question which was indeed about the rim. But as to tires, I think your comment is wrong. Sometimes, there's little external evidence of sidewall damage and the tire holds air, but there's also deep damage not visible, and the tire fails later seeming without cause. I think the approach should be: if there's *any* sidewall damage (not "the tire still holds air") the tire should be replaced.